# How to prioritize OR order and account for NULLs in JOIN ON statement for multiple tables in Teradata SQL?

Tags: sql, syntax, null, teradata

I'm trying to join `TABLEONE (a)` and `TABLETWO (b)` on three key columns to then return a description `DESC` for roughly 1 billion rows of data.

While one of these columns is an easy join (`a.TS = b.UCDE`), the other two have various rules which need to be executed in a specific order so they can match properly.

I'm having trouble accounting for this behaviour, specifically with what happens when certain columns have NULL values.

The rules are:

1. `a.TS = b.UCDE` (always)
2. If `a.ICI IS NOT NULL` then check to see if it matches `b.STM` given 1.

a. If it finds a match, go to 3.

b. If it does not find a match (i.e. `b.STM IS NULL`), then return `DESC` for that row.

c. If `a.ICI IS NULL` then join to the row where `b.STM IS NULL` given 1.

3. `a.S_ID` can be either `0000000000`, `NULL`, or a value like `0000000300` while `b.SRL` will either be `NULL` or a value like `000300` (Note: `a.S_ID` has 10 characters and `b.SRL` only has 6, so the join is on the right 6 characters of `a.S_ID`)

a. The priority should be on `RIGHT(a.S_ID,6) = b.SRL` if there's a match

b. If `a.S_ID = 0000000000` or `IS NULL`, this can join to `b.SRL IS NULL`, though effectively the join is redundant as 1. and 2. should be sufficient in this case.

```
SELECT a.TDATE, a.AMT, a.ISI, a.TS, b.UCDE, a.ICI, b.STM, a.S_ID,
CASE WHEN b.SRL1 IS NULL THEN '0000000000' ELSE b.SRL1 END AS SRL, a.RES,
-- Manually override certain conditions
CASE WHEN (a.ISI = 'AP' AND a.TS = '1234') THEN 'APP'
     WHEN (a.ISI = 'JK' AND a.TS = '1234') THEN 'JAX'
     ELSE b.DESC END AS DESC
FROM TABLEONE as a
FULL JOIN TABLETWO AS b
    ON  ( a.TS = b.UCDE
        AND (a.ICI = b.STM OR (a.ICI IS NULL and b.STM IS NULL) OR b.STM IS NULL)
        AND (RIGHT(a.S_ID,6) = RIGHT(SRL,6) OR a.S_ID IS NULL)
        )
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN STM IS NULL THEN 2 ELSE 1 END)
```

My current code works inconsistently and in some cases, I'm getting duplicates from the `OR b.STM IS NULL` or `OR a.S_ID IS NULL`. In other cases, it seems to work fine.

I've been reworking it as I go along but the inconsistent results are confusing and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong or if there's a better way to deal with the NULL conditions?

---

**EDIT to add an example** (`EXPECTED DESC` is my expected result):

```
TABLE A:
+----+------------+-----+-----+------+--------+------------+-----+---------------+
| #  |   TDATE    | AMT | ISI |  TS  |  ICI   |    S_ID    | RES | EXPECTED DESC |
+----+------------+-----+-----+------+--------+------------+-----+---------------+
|  1 | 2019-09-01 |  94 | DC  | 1001 | 1A     | 0000000300 | PX  | A             |
|  2 | 2019-09-01 |  35 | DC  | 1001 | 2B     | 0000000300 | DL  | B             |
|  3 | 2019-09-01 |  40 | DC  | 1001 | 2B     | 0000000600 | JI  | C             |
|  4 | 2019-09-01 |  65 | DC  | 1001 | 2B     | <NULL>     | WO  | D             |
|  5 | 2019-09-02 |  95 | AC  | 1001 | 2B     | 0000000000 | FK  | D             |
|  6 | 2019-09-03 |  10 | AC  | 1001 | 3C     | <NULL>     | SL  | E             |
|  7 | 2019-09-04 |   8 | AC  | 1001 | 3C     | 0000000000 | FH  | E             |
|  8 | 2019-09-05 |  40 | DC  | 1001 | 3C     | 0000000600 | WO  | E             |
|  9 | 2019-09-06 |  65 | DC  | 1001 | 4D     | <NULL>     | FK  | F             |
| 10 | 2019-09-07 |  95 | AC  | 1001 | 4D     | 0000000000 | SL  | F             |
| 11 | 2019-09-08 |  10 | AC  | 1001 | 4D     | 0000000600 | FH  | F             |
| 12 | 2019-09-09 |   8 | AC  | 1001 | <NULL> | 0000000300 | WO  | G             |
| 13 | 2019-09-10 |  40 | DC  | 1001 | <NULL> | 0000000500 | FK  | H             |
| 14 | 2019-09-11 |  65 | DC  | 1001 | <NULL> | <NULL>     | SL  | I             |
| 15 | 2019-09-12 |  95 | AC  | 1001 | <NULL> | 0000000000 | FH  | I             |
+----+------------+-----+-----+------+--------+------------+-----+---------------+
```

```
TABLE B:
+------+--------+--------+------+
| UCDE |  STM   |  SRL   | DESC |
+------+--------+--------+------+
| 1001 | 1A     | 000300 | A    |
| 1001 | 2B     | 000300 | B    |
| 1001 | 2B     | 000600 | C    |
| 1001 | 2B     | <NULL> | D    |
| 1001 | 3C     | <NULL> | E    |
| 1001 | 4D     | <NULL> | F    |
| 1001 | <NULL> | 000300 | G    |
| 1001 | <NULL> | 000500 | H    |
| 1001 | <NULL> | <NULL> | I    |
+------+--------+--------+------+
```

Comment: I think sample data and desired results would be a big help.

Comment: Fair enough. I've added a sample of the two tables with the desired result being the `EXPECTED DESC` column. Does that help?

Comment: I doubt you can get your result without a 2nd join or some ROW_NUMBER. How big is tabletwo and many STM/SRLs exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand you're trying to join `TABLEONE` and `TABLETWO` on these conditions:

1. `a.TS = b.UCDE`
2. `a.ICI IS NOT NULL AND a.ICI = b.STM` and Logic #3; otherwise join on `b.STM IS NULL`
3. `RIGHT(a.S_ID,6) = b.SRL`; otherwise if `a.S_ID = 0000000000 or IS NULL`, join on `b.SRL IS NULL`

I took the logic you specified and re-worked your `JOIN` condition:

```sql
SELECT a.TDATE, a.AMT, a.ISI, a.TS, b.UCDE, a.ICI, b.STM, a.S_ID,
CASE WHEN b.SRL1 IS NULL THEN '0000000000' ELSE b.SRL1 END AS SRL, a.RES,
-- Manually override certain conditions
CASE WHEN (a.ISI = 'AP' AND a.TS = '1234') THEN 'APP'
     WHEN (a.ISI = 'JK' AND a.TS = '1234') THEN 'JAX'
     ELSE b.DESC END AS DESC
FROM TABLEONE AS a
FULL OUTER JOIN TABLETWO AS b ON a.TS = b.UCDE
  AND (
    (
      a.ICI = b.STM AND -- a.ICI IS NOT NULL --> check for match on b.STM (NULL <> NULL)
      (
        (RIGHT(a.S_ID, 6) = b.SRL) OR -- Priority should be on RIGHT(a.S_ID,6) = b.SRL
        (COALESCE(a.S_ID, 0000000000) = 0000000000 AND b.SRL IS NULL)
      )
    ) OR
    (a.ICI IS NULL AND b.STM IS NULL) -- a.ICI IS NULL then join on b.STM IS NULL
  )
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN STM IS NULL THEN 2 ELSE 1 END)
```

I don't have a `TD` system to test, but give it a try and let me know how it turns out.

Also, I don't quite follow this line `If it does not find a match (i.e. b.STM IS NULL), then return DESC for that row.`  I assume that's logic you have in your `CASE` expression in your `SELECT` so I didn't touch that part.

**Update**
Here's a truth table based on the query in my answer:

```
Case    a.ICI   b.STM   "Match" Join rows?
------------------------------------------
1       NULL    NULL    NO      YES
2       5E      NULL    NO      NO
3       NULL    6B      NO      NO
4       5E      6B      NO      NO
5       5E      5E      YES     Logic #3 (a.S_ID = b.SRL?)
```

Is this the logic you're looking for?  If you're getting the rows you expect, then you can just add a `COALESCE` or `CASE` statement in your `SELECT` to display the correct `DESC` value.

If the logic in the table above is not what you want and you're not getting the expected rows, then based on your comment of having `b.STM IS NULL` as a catch-all, I think you could just modify this line `(a.ICI IS NULL AND b.STM IS NULL)` to be simply `(b.STM IS NULL)`.  That would cause the join to work for Case #2.

Comment: Hi Ravioli, thanks for this -- it is VERY close to what I am looking for! What I mean by `If it does not find a match (i.e. b.STM IS NULL), then return DESC for that row.` is that `b.STM IS NULL` is a 'catch-all' for when there is no match `a.ICI <> b.STM` -- the description on the NULL row should be returned. Is that possible? I was thinking something similar to that `COALESCE` line that you put in.

Comment: To further elaborate, there are some scenarios where `a.ICI = 5E` (i.e. `IS NOT NULL`) but there is no corresponding `b.STM = 5E`. In this case, it should match to the row where `b.STM IS NULL` as a 'catch-all', given the first condition `a.TS = b.UCDE`.

Comment: You're welcome.  See my updated answer above and let me know if I understood correctly.

Comment: Yeah, after mulling over it on the weekend, I've come to the conclusion that it isn't logically possible to match rows in the scenario where `a.ICI = 5E` and there isn't a corresponding `b.STM = 5E` match without also inviting a whole bunch of duplicates.

I've ended up using a CASE statement to hard-code those scenarios instead. It's not ideal as there are quite a number of them, but it's the only thing that actually works.

Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you can get the expected result using a single join without multiple rows matching, which must be removed using an OLAP function like ROW_NUMBER (can be quite expensive on a large table).

Try a 2nd join to `tabletwo` (of course, then you need `COALESCE` for each column from that table):

```
SELECT a.TDATE, a.AMT, a.ISI, a.TS,
   Coalesce(b1.UCDE, b2.UCDE), a.ICI,
   Coalesce(b1.STM,  b2.STM), a.S_ID,
   Coalesce(b1.SRL,  b2.SRL, '0000000000') AS SRL,
   a.RES,
   -- Manually override certain conditions
   CASE
      WHEN (a.ISI = 'AP' AND a.TS = '1234') THEN 'APP'
      WHEN (a.ISI = 'JK' AND a.TS = '1234') THEN 'JAX'
      ELSE Coalesce(b1.DESC, b2.DESC)
   END AS DESC_
FROM tableone AS a
LEFT JOIN tabletwo AS b1
  ON a.TS = b1.UCDE
 AND (a.ICI = b1.STM OR (a.ICI IS NULL AND b1.STM IS NULL))
 AND (Coalesce(Right(a.S_ID,6), '000000') = Coalesce(b1.SRL, '000000'))
LEFT JOIN tabletwo AS b2
  ON a.TS = b2.UCDE
 AND (a.ICI = b2.STM OR (a.ICI IS NULL AND b2.STM IS NULL))
 AND b1.UCDE IS NULL -- join only if no match based on SRL, yet
```

Performance will mainly depend on the PI of tableone and the number of rows in tabletwo.